# how to activate a profile in order to create table on my sql using spring boot jpa?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mysql-workbench

I am trying to create a spring boot data JPA project. I already created a table in my SQL but the columns are not being added. I browsed the internet for solutions and I added what's necessary for pom.xml. Could it be a problem with the SQL version?

[pom.xml error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98vhG.png)

[error when running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQCSD.png) 
[properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZYND.png)

This is the table I am trying to create on my MySQL database

```
    @SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_USER")
public class User implements Serializable {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id; 
    
    private String firstName; 
    
    private String lastName;
    
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateNaissance;
    
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    Role role; 
    
    @Transient
    private String age; 

    
    public User() {}

    public User(String firstName, String lastName, Date dateNaissance, Role role) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.dateNaissance = dateNaissance;
        this.role = role;
    }

    public User(Long id, String firstName, String lastName, Date dateNaissance, Role role) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.dateNaissance = dateNaissance;
        this.role = role;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", dateNaissance="
                + dateNaissance + ", role=" + role + "]";
    }
    
    
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String fName) {
        this.firstName = fName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lName) {
        this.lastName = lName;
    }
    public Date getDateNaissance() {
        return dateNaissance;
    }
    public void setDateNaissance(Date dateNaissance) {
        this.dateNaissance = dateNaissance;
    }
    public Role getRole() {
        return role;
    }
    public void setRole(Role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
    

}
```

Comment: error: Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured

Comment: can you attach your entity?

Answer (score 0):

Does your pom file contain mysql dependency? Have you checked?

if not then add below maven dependencicy:--

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
             <version>8.0.16</version>
        </dependency>
```

also change the property key field as below:---(check with any of these two)

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
OR,
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

2nd solution:--
you can exclude DataSourceAutoConfiguration class :----

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
```

Comment: I tried the solutions you suggested but stil the same error in pom.xml

Comment: that is not the problem . please update the project like maven->update project->ok or u can just change the spring boot version"2.1.4-SNAPSHOT"

Comment: leave pom.xml my question is now whether you are able to run your service or not?

Comment: Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Action:
Consider the following:
 If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
 If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).

Comment: I Updated the project but I still get the same problem. And please tell me what does it have to do with spring boot version ?

Comment: can you check there is sql jar or not in your local maven repo , if not then either add jar in build-path or provide jar location in pom like:--<scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/Name_Your_JAR.jar</systemPath>

Comment: I'm sorry but I think I'm not able to run a server . How do I check?

Comment: dude..can you attach log here?

Comment: you are supposed to add "@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })" main class. the which is having main method().

Comment: My problem was solved! I chose a superior spring boot version and my server was not on !